# EMail subject get set in CP1252 encoding even though the string is in UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, jakarta-mail

The file new1.txt contains UTF-8 string which is sent as subject. But the received email will show the string in CP1252 format. But if I set console encoding by going to Run Config->Common Tab and set console encoding as UTF-8, I can see UTF-string properly in the recieved email. I using google server for this test:

Not working:
æ—¥æœ¬ : Partner Name: ã‚¢ã‚¹ãƒˆãƒ©ã‚¼ãƒ?ã‚«æ ªå¼?ä¼šç¤¾ :

Working:
 日本 : Partner Name: アストラゼネカ株式会社

My Code:
        final String username = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
        final String password = "xxxxxx";

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
            }
        });

    try {
        File fileDir = new File("c:\\new1.txt");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));

        String str;
        String str1 ="";

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str1 += str;
        }

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("xxxx@xxxxx.com"));
        message.setSubject(str1);
        MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
        body.setContent("This is a Test EMail. Please ignore", "text/html");
        body.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        mp.addBodyPart(body);
        byte[] attachmentData = str1.getBytes();
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(attachmentData,"application/octet-stream"));
        MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachment.setDataHandler(dh);
        attachment.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
        attachment.setFileName("new1.txt");
        mp.addBodyPart(attachment);

        message.setContent(mp);
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");
```

thanks
Madhu

Following are the code changes I made in my J2EE app. In this it is adding 3 files as attachments. One of the 3 files is the subject itself. In the attachment (Subject.txt) conent is fine.

```
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s);

    ....

    message.setSubject(subject,"UTF-8");// MimeUtility.encodeText(subject,"UTF-8", "B"));

    ...

            MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
            body.setContent(sm.getMailBody(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            body.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
            mp.addBodyPart(body);
```

[The debug message. I could not add it as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpDEW.png)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This solution worked. But this is my test program. This solution is not working in my J2EE app. In this app I am using sendmail as the mail server in Aix and J2EE app is running on WebSPhere Process Server 7.0.

Comment: Can you describe the differences? You might want so set  props.put("mail.debug", "true"); and capture the output and edit your question - this will contain raw message data and the encoded header field that's broken

Comment: This is the  debug message:

Comment: didn't go through - edit your question please.

Comment: This is the  debug message:Message-ID: Subject: =?UTF-8?B?SUJNIFBPOiDDpsKXwqXDpsKcwqwgOiBQYXJ0bmVyIE5hbWU6IMOjwoLCog==?=
 =?UTF-8?B?w6PCgsK5w6PCg8KIw6PCg8Kpw6PCgsK8w6PCg8KNw6PCgg==?=
 =?UTF-8?B?wqvDpsKgwqrDpcK8wo/DpMK8wprDp8Kkwr4gOiBQ?=
 =?UTF-8?B?Tz03MTAwMDEzOTAzIDogUHJvZHVjdElkZW50aWZpZXI9ZA==?=
 =?UTF-8?B?NGI4ZWRjNi04MzM2LTExZTUtOTE0Yy0zM2I0NmRkMTVhYWI=?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_327_1055145700.1450101410813"

------=_Part_327_1055145700.1450101410813
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Comment: Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=HTMLBody.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=HTMLBody.htm
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=7100013903.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=Subject.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Subject.txt

Comment: please don't post this as comment - if you put it in your question (together with the changes you made to the code), it's much better to read.

Comment: I am having trouble putting this in the question. It is not saving the content being added.  I will try again

Comment: then maybe only the lines from Message-ID: until MIME-Version (so basically: your subject)

Comment: okay - checked your subject. This is not correct UTF-8 for your text. You're sure the file on the server containing the subject is UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Subject would need to be encoded using [MimeUtility.encodeText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#encodeText(java.lang.String)).

**But** as Bill Shannon pointed out: Don't do this by encoding it manually, call [`MimeMessage.setSubject(String subject, String charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSubject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead. Otherwise setSubject will internally encode resulting string with platform encoding which might cause trouble.

One more thing:

```
    byte[] attachmentData = str1.getBytes();
```

Retrieves bytes in *platform encoding* - which might not be utf-8. Try

```
    byte[] attachmentData = str1.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Message to be a MimeMessage and then use the [setSubject method that allows you to specify the charset](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSubject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: which internally uses MimeUtility.encodeText... so if the one does not work, the other most likely will not work as well.

Comment: MimeUtility is there for the rare cases where JavaMail can't or won't handle these issues for you.  This is one of those cases where it can.  Why make it more complicated?  Just use the API that's there for exactly this reason.

Comment: In general: Yes, absolutely. In this case: In order to explain what needs to be done to make it work, doing it manually will hopefully add understanding of how it needs to be done. I guess it's a question of "just fix it" and "why is it breaking?" :-)

Comment: The setSubject method is always going to choose a charset and encode accordingly.  You either get the default or you get the one you specify.  If you encode it manually before passing it to the setText method, it's still going to try to encode it again using the default charset.  Since you're passing it ASCII after the manual encoding, the second encoding will likely be a nop.  Still, it's wrong to try to encode it twice.

Comment: Right. That makes sense.